# Error trying to migrate my database. Typing error

Tags: python, django, django-settings, django-database

Sorry but I don't know what is happening when I try to run (python3 manage.py makemigrations).

I really don't know what's going on I'm looking for an answer for a while but I can't figure out where the error is:

```
(paginas) root@janstar:/home/paginas/proyectodedjango# python3 manage.py makemigrations
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/paginas/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 328, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/paginas/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 369, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/paginas/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 83, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/paginas/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py", line 101, in handle
    loader.check_consistent_history(connection)
  File "/home/paginas/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 283, in check_consistent_history
    applied = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "/home/paginas/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 76, in applied_migrations
    if self.has_table():
  File "/home/paginas/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 56, in has_table
    return self.Migration._meta.db_table in self.connection.introspection.table_names(self.connection.cursor())
  File "/home/paginas/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/paginas/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 260, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "/home/paginas/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 236, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/home/paginas/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/paginas/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 220, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/home/paginas/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/paginas/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 197, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/home/paginas/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/paginas/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 199, in get_new_connection
    conn = Database.connect(**conn_params)
TypeError: argument 1 must be str, not PosixPath

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/paginas/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/paginas/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/paginas/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 341, in run_from_argv
    connections.close_all()
  File "/home/paginas/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 230, in close_all
    connection.close()
  File "/home/paginas/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/paginas/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 261, in close
    if not self.is_in_memory_db():
  File "/home/paginas/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 380, in is_in_memory_db
    return self.creation.is_in_memory_db(self.settings_dict['NAME'])
  File "/home/paginas/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/creation.py", line 12, in is_in_memory_db
    return database_name == ':memory:' or 'mode=memory' in database_name
TypeError: argument of type 'PosixPath' is not iterable
```

[Try changing this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYoHx.png)
[For this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRfg2.png)

Sorry if I added the images wrong I'm new to this page.

This is my settings.py file:
"""

```
    from pathlib import Path
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-k3d35^_5m3-=t-7&-!4qq78o+h%-ra6atz-a9m1)19a7()$8u2'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['31.220.48.123']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'ckeditor',
    'mainapp',
    'pages.apps.PagesConfig',
    'blog.apps.BlogConfig', 
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'ProyectoDjango.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'pages.context_processors.get_pages',
                'blog.processor.get_categories',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'ProyectoDjango.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.sqlite3",
        "NAME": BASE_DIR / "db.sqlite3",
    }
}

"""
DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
            'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
        }
    }
"""

"""
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'proyectodjango',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '12345',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': 3306
    }
}
"""

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'es-es'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

# Media
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

"""

and this is my manage.py file:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgnFr.png)

Answer (score 0):

In the error message it says that you need a string instead of 'PosixPath' try turning the path into a string.

Comment: Could you tell me which part you are referring to?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use:

```py
DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
            'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry I just tried it but it doesn't work, still the same error

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can try this way:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}
```

After adding above code in `settings.py` file, first you need to delete `db` file and delete all `migration folders` of each app and then run below commands:

```
python manage.py makemigrations appname

python manage.py sqlmigrate appname 0001

python manage.py migrate
```

And now your problem will solve.

Comment: Sorry it doesn't seem to work

Comment: what happened exactly after doing above things